# loading none AMD module before any other code in RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, amd

How can I load a none AMD module before any other modules are loaded? I have a shim for the console.x but having trouble loading this before anything else.

also I wish to load it only if a condition is true - so in this case as it is a console shim, I want to test to see if 'console' is undefined, then only load the console shim if the condition is true.

to note I am using RequireJS and do have Modernizr to hand as well.

Thanks.

Comment: `<script src="console-shim.js"></script>` then `<script src="require.js"></script>`?

Comment: thanks but I forgot to add an extra condition, see above in the text. any thoughts?

Comment: Is it imperative that it is only loaded conditionally? Can you not just load the shim always and have some `if ("undefined" === typeof window["console"]) { ... }` condition in the shim code?

Comment: yes it is imperitive, I am also using requireJS, have tried to use YepNope from Modernizr with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This demo shows a rudimentary way of doing what you want.

The following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/bZB9L/6/

```
<script>
if ("undefined" === typeof window["mozInnerScreenX"]) {
    document.writeln("<script src=http://jsbin.com/erevub/4></scr" + "ipt>");
}
</script>
<script>
alert(mozInnerScreenX);
</script>
```

imports from this script:

http://jsbin.com/erevub/4

```
window["mozInnerScreenX"] = window["mozInnerScreenX"] || (function () {
    return 999;
}());
```

I've used `mozInnerScreenX` as the shim property, as all browsers on my machine have `console`.

The first script block that uses `document.writeln` must be in a separate script block to the following script that uses the shim.

There are lots of reasons why `document.writeln` is a bad idea, but I don't know your full use case, so this is simplest.

I get an alert for `999` on IE and Chrome (shim value), and `1074.5` on Firefox (real value).